# What symbols are used after base 36

Tags: computer-science

Since Hex (base 16) uses 0-9A-F, and (I'm assuming here) Base 17 uses 0-9A-G and so on. What symbols are used once 0-9A-Z are all used up.

Comment: THanks all, I still think that lower case should not be considered different.

Comment: @Preet - why? It is the computer that needs to interpret them, and the computer knows that 'a' != 'A'... base-64 is so ubiquitous that this isn't going to change

Comment: by convention, I've not noticed any language I've used where hex 0x10A != 0x10a

Comment: I agree with Mike. 0x10A is just a symbol. After all thats what you asked as well, "what symbols are used after..." Notice that all other numbering schemes line up on bit boundaries; 16, 32, 64. This ends up having other advantages too.

Comment: @PreetSangha: That's because hexadecimal doesn't have an A and an a so when you type 0x10a it's unambiguous that you mean 0x10A. You'll find a computer DOES think A and a are different in Base64 because both are valid and different in that base.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no standard answer for your question. "Base 36" is coincidentally convenient to talk about because:

1. Hexadecimal conventionally uses 0-9a-f, so it's "obvious" to keep going through the alphabet.
2. The Roman/ASCII alphabet runs out of steam at 'z'.
3. Base 36 (regardless of how you represent it) is mildly interesting from a Mathematical perspective because 36 has so many divisors.

However, there's no universally-accepted convention for what sequence of characters one might venture into after 'z'.

Comment: Until you get to base64. That's fairly standardised.

Comment: @Colin, I understood the original question to be about mathematical bases. The "base" in "Base64" doesn't really mean the same thing.

Comment: Actually, it does. Base 10 merely means that you represent a large number by a string of characters over an alphabet of size 10. Base 16 is a representation of a large number by a string, with an alphabet of size 16. Base 64 is a representation of a file=large number as a string of characters over an alphabet of size 64.

Comment: Actually the Roman alphabet does not have 26 letters. The letters U and J are recent inventions in the past 500 years. The English alphabet on the other hand has 26 letters.

Answer (score 25):

Well, look at [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64): 0-9, A-Z, a-z and then a few symbols depending on the context. (Base64 for the web tends to be different to other schemes to avoid URL/HTML encoding issues.)

Answer (score 16):

Digital clocks (base-60) use base-10 numbers as symbols and separate them with a separator symbol (like ':'). This way you'd never run out of symbols!

Answer (score 12):

The Babylonians used Sexagesimal math with base 10 numbers in groupings to form base 60 digits for the various 60's places. (This is where we get all the base-60 math used in angles and time.) This is probably the oldest precedent for the method of creating some some form of base-N digit using base-10 numbers.

Comment: wow thanks - that's really interesting. I always wondered about the 60 but never enough to look it up.

Comment: I believe that they didn't use 6 groups of 10 but 5 groups of 12. As with all really old math it has it roots in using our fingers. Left hand is the number of 12s. Right hand is 1 - 12. Place your thumb to index tip for 1, middle tip is 2 ..., thumb to behind the index first knuckle is 5, behind the index 2nd knuckle is 9. You can extrapolate the rest. You could really go up to 71 in this way before running out of fingers but I guess they decided to stop after the last full carry.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal#Babylonian_mathematics for the cuneiform digits.

Comment: @Dinah: They used symbols representing 1s, 10s, 60s, 600s, 3600s, etc., where all odd and all even groups used the same symbols (differing only by position).  So nix on the "5 12s" theory.

Answer (score 10):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) adds the lowercase characters and + and /.

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to write IPv4 adresses can be viewed as a base 256 representation, where decimal numbers are separated by points.

Answer (score 5):

well there's base64, and then Pokemon characters

Comment: @Coxy: There are some 500+ Pokémon these days. Believe me, <s>I</s> my little sister regularly plays the game.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Greek and Hebrew are two likely candidates, as they are used in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for 0-9, then A-Z capitals, then alpha to omega in lower case.  That gets you to 60.  After that, I'd go with Jeremy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

chinese maybe? wikipedia says that there are 47,035 characters in the Kangxi Dictionary!

Comment: And the fun part is, data encoded in baseChinese can produce poetry as a side effect. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

That's easy: 0..9 ++ A..Z ++ a..z ++ 阿..中.  Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: see my comment about upper and lower cases

Comment: @Preet Sangha: OK, so you read my answer and what leaps out at you as being ridiculous is the upper and lower cases?!

Comment: I don't see why. The reason I asked the question originally was that on every computer I've debugged upper and lower case was treated as the same when using numbering systems.

Comment: So the upper and lower cases leaped out as ridiculous, but the Chinese characters didn't?

Answer (score 0):

[RAD50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIX-50) got it to 40 (which is 50 in octal), not quite following this sequence.  But hex wasn't so common then.  Nor was lowercase.